# stick button to bottom of element

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to stick child button element to bottom of parent element when number of child elements vary?

Parent element is fixed height, and could be scrolled vertically in case of child overflow. In that case, button should be at the end of child list, but in case there is no children, or children size don't push parent element to overflow, it should be at bottom of parent element.

Is there pure css solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to do a quick mock-up graphic?

Comment: @VinnyBurgh pretty sure he wants it like this http://jsfiddle.net/47UUM/ except with the button hidden at the bottom of the parent div. This is a tricky problem.

Comment: @VinnyBurgh - I understand it same as having a sticky footer inside a panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edited for a more solid approach:

Basically if I understand correctly you could use the [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) logic - just inside a panel:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>asdfasdfasdfadfs</p>
            <!--<p>asdfasdfasdfadfs<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>-->
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <button>Click click!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-container {width:300px;height:300px;margin:20px;background:#f2f2f2;overflow:auto;}
.panel-content {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -30px; 
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 30px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
.footer {background:#ccc;}
```

Working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/9SHdN/47/ (uncomment the commented out `<p>` to see scroll on long text)

Comment: i think he wants the button to be under the overflow area - hidden until scrolled down.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i don't know if i really understand your question but here is a try:

The parent div:

```
<div class="options_div"> 
   <p>Text inside</p>

   <ul class="options">
       <li>option 1</li>
       <li>option 2</li>
       <li>option 3</li>
   </ul>

   <input type="button" name="go" value="Goooo!" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.options_div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.options_div>ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.options_div>ul>li {
    /* do what everrrr you want with it */
}
```

This code generates a div that's 200px high with the button in the bottom. If there are any options in the ul, then the button gets pushed down and will always stay on the end of the list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I try this, but if you have too many li elements, when scroll appear, button remain at same height. It should be at the end of list (not visible before scroll)

Comment: I updated the code. The position absolute placed the button at the bottom of the div element instead of the end of the list. I removed the positioning of the button, it should now be at the bottom.

Comment: No. Now is on the end of list, but not on the bottom of parent div, if there is no scroll. You clearly did not understood question

Comment: It seems that you already had the answer. Indeed, I still don't understand your question, please try to to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

```
.panel {position:relative;height:300px;width:300px;background:#f2f2f2;overflow:auto;}

.varyingContent { height:280px; display:table-cell; }

.button { position:relative; height:20px;}

<div class="panel">
        <div class="varyingContent">
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        asdfadf
        <br />
        <br />
        </div>
        <button class="button">test</button>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps